# Hiding the Root View of a UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uitoolbar

For the app that i am developing i have used a UISplitViewController as my base, but have modified, or attempting to modify the split view controller like that of Alice Bevan–McGregor's on http://vimeo.com/13054813. However in my app i have a table view with a list of options, and every time i click on an option it loads the corresponding detail page from a detached nib file. So, at the start of my app i can see and use the hidesidebar fine though it displays a white page. when i choose an option, the toolbar is overridden by the corresponding nib, so it dissapears. What i am not sure about is how to connect it in a way that it appears on every page(nib) everytime i choose an option from the tableview. I have been stuck with this problem for quite a while now.

essentially i would like the toolbar to maintain its functionality no matter what page i am on.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should give a try to this http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad

It has the following method

```
- (IBAction)toggleMasterView:(id)sender;
```

My own implementation of custom splitview using navigation based app @ https://github.com/palaniraja/cUISplitViewController

Also try Salva's implementation http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2011/05/custom-uisplitviewcontroller-for-ipad.html

Comment: thanks for links. perfect, exactly what i needed. Just one question, do you if with the mgsplitviewcontroller i can import the code i need to my existing project or would it be a safer option to just us the project provided as a template?

Comment: @user692950 I guess importing the files and changing the UISplitViewController to MGSplitviewController should do fine.